# Problems to post a tweet with php

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using this code to get the last 20 tweets I was mentioned in.
But I can't adapt it to be able to tweet a simple text tweet. can someone help me?
I tried everything but i'm stuck.
I dont know what to do...
I know I have to post to /update.json , and use update -> text
but its not working

```
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}
function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}
function returnTweet(){
    $oauth_access_token         = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $oauth_access_token_secret  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $consumer_key               = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $consumer_secret            = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $timeline               = "mentions_timeline";  
    //  create request
        $requestrt = array(
            'screen_name'       => 'myScreenName', 
            'extended_entities' => 'true',
            'exclude_replies' => 'true',
            'include_rts' => 'false',
            'tweet_mode' => 'extended',
            'count'             => '20');
    $oauth = array(
        'oauth_consumer_key'        => $consumer_key,
        'oauth_nonce'               => time(),
        'oauth_signature_method'    => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_token'               => $oauth_access_token,
        'oauth_timestamp'           => time(),
        'oauth_version'             => '1.0' 
    );
    //  merge request and oauth to one array
        $oauth = array_merge($oauth, $requestrt);
        $base_info = buildBaseString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/$timeline.json", 'GET', $oauth);
        $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
        $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
        $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;
    //  make request
        $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
        $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                          CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                          CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/$timeline.json?". http_build_query($requestrt),
                          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);
        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $json = curl_exec($feed);
        curl_close($feed);
    return json_decode($json, true); 
}
$tweet = returnTweet();
```

Comment: Please explain what "not working"  actually means. Where does it fail? What really happens? Error messages? Wrong response? Have you done any type of debugging to narrow the problem down?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried and what the outcomes were of those attempts

Comment: What is the error please